# how to get greatest() column value and name from list[str] containing column names in pyspark sql?

Tags: sql, list, pyspark, greatest-n-per-group, sql-function

I have the following sample code:

```
lst1 = ["a", "b"]
for ls1 in lst1:
    new_lst = []
    lst2 = ["d", "e", "f"]
    for ls2 in lst2:
        new_lst.append(ls1 + ls2)
        df = (df.withColumn("final_" + ls1, greatest(*new_lst))
```

Is this the correct way to get the max value from the list of columns in each loop? Also any way to get the corresponding column name as well?

example:

input df =>

```
ad    ae    af    bd    be    bf    cd    ce    cf
--------------------------------------------------
10    11    12    13    14    15    16    17    18
19    20    21    22    23    24    25    26    27
28    29    30    31    32    33    34    35    36
```

expected output df =>

```
ad    ae    af    final_a    bd    be    bf    final_b
------------------------------------------------------
10    11    12    12         13    14    15    15
19    20    21    21         22    23    24    24
28    29    30    30         31    32    33    33
```

Thanks!

Comment: The  last row with "df = ..." should be outside the second (inner) loop but inside the first loop, so you should move it four positions left

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the maximum value of columns where it has the same prefix like "a", "b", "c", then this will work.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

columns = df.columns
prefixs = set(map(lambda c: c[0], columns))

for prefix in prefixs:
    df = df.withColumn('final_' + prefix, f.array_max(f.array(*[f.col(c) for c in columns if c.startswith(prefix)])))
    
df.show()

+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+-------+-------+-------+
| ad| ae| af| bd| be| bf| cd| ce| cf|final_c|final_a|final_b|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+-------+-------+-------+
| 10| 11| 12| 13| 14| 15| 16| 17| 18|     18|     12|     15|
| 19| 20| 21| 22| 23| 24| 25| 26| 27|     27|     21|     24|
| 28| 29| 30| 31| 32| 33| 34| 35| 36|     36|     30|     33|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+-------+-------+-------+
```